# C++ - Comparing Strings Function not working?

Tags: c++, html, string, pointers, tokenize

I am currently writing an HTML token recognizer in c++. I am using stacks to check and see if there are beginning and matching tags.

Before I can match my tags I need to make sure that the tag is valid. But for some reason my checking function is not working. I step through each step in the algorithm and from everything i see this should work. Yet it is returning false every time. Here is my code:

```
const int NUM_TAGS = 12;
char *tagNames[NUM_TAGS] = 
{
    "<html>",
    "</html>",
    "<head>",
    "</head>",
    "<title>",
    "</title>",
    "<body>",
    "</body>",
    "<p>",
    "</p>",
    "</>",
    "<SPOT/>",
};

bool check_ValidTag(char check[])
{
    for (int i=0; i<=NUM_TAGS; i++)
    {       
        if (check==tagNames[i])
             return true;
    }

    return false;
};
```

I am calling the function like this:

```
 tok.isValid = check_ValidTag((char*)tok.str);
```

As Requested Here is what the struct "tok" looks like..

```
struct token 
{
  char name[MAX_NAME + 1];
  int type;
  bool isValid;
  char str[MAX_LENGTH + 1];
 };
```

Any Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I do not see where temp is defined.

Comment: Any reason why the slash trails SPOT?  (Maybe it's its own tag?)

Comment: I accidentally left temp in... I meant to change it to char. I did that when I coppied the code over on accident. Sorry

Comment: Let us know what happens after you make the changes listed below johnny.

Comment: The name `tagNames` for the variable sounds weird, since the variable contains `<body>`, which is not really a name. I would rather only put `body` into that array. That way you can handle `<p class="green">`, too. To make the code look more like good C++, I would use a `std::vector<std::string>` instead of a `const char **`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other people pointed out, you are comparing a pointer to char array (not the actual string content). If you can change the implementation to use std::string, the "==" overloaded operator should do the trick for you.

However, if you need to stick with the char array. Do it c-style:

```
{
  if(strcmp(check, tagNames[i])==0)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing pointers, not the strings' contents.  Replace

```
 char *tagNames[NUM_TAGS] =
```

with

```
std::string tagNames[NUM_TAGS] =
```

Answer (score 1):

The `==` operator on `char *` doesn't compare the *contents* of the strings. It compares the *addresses* of the strings. If you are working with C-style strings you should use [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/) to compare them.

However since this is tagged as C++ I would recommend that you use `std::string` instead of `char *`.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you like to stay c-plus-plussy, you could use the `compare()` function from `char_traits<char>`.

```
typedef std::char_traits<char> ct;

bool check_ValidTag(char check[])
{
    size_t check_len = ct::length(check);
    for (int i=0; i<=NUM_TAGS; i++)
    {       
        if( 0 == ct::compare(check, tagNames[i], check_len) )
            return true;
    }

    return false;
};
```

See the [documentation at www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/char_traits/).